# Does Facebook Connect have a javascript API that doesn't open a new window?

Tags: javascript, api, facebook

I want it to have a popup dialog javascript box. Instead of a new window.
I've seen it before. How can I get it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, Facebook prohibits using a javascript pop-up instead of a new window. Until early this year, they weren't doing anything to block it, so some sites were doing it that way.

Now they've started detecting when they're in an iframe and are [putting up a black overlay](http://forum.developers.facebook.com/viewtopic.php?pid=200623) that, when clicked, opens their login in a new window. At least their implementation still allows sites that are doing it the "wrong" way to work with no changes, but it's frustrating.

It's *possible* to work around this using their mechanisms for client authentication, but that involves your web site prompting for the user for their Facebook password which is a horrible idea for security and privacy reasons as well as an explicit break of Facebook TOS.